# Creating object vs setting individual values for passing values between activities in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have to pass some data related to user between to activities, data is

```
name, user id, user name, email
```

now to do this I have to put these values in Intent and pass to other activity.
Now there a two ways

1)
Create a DTO for User say UserDto and make it Serializable and pass it using intent

```
intent.putExtra("user",userDto);
```

2)
put all four different values in intent as

```
intent.putExtra("name",name);
intent.putExtra("userid",id);
intent.putExtra("username",username);
intent.putExtra("email",email);
```

which one of above is most optimized way,

Please recommend some other way of maintaining user throughout the application scope.

Comment: use `sharedpreference`. SharedPreference get deleted only if you uninstall you application

Comment: @SathishKumar No. SharedPreferences are not intended for passing data between activities. That is why we have Intents and Extras

Comment: manish, prefer Parcelable over Serializable whenever possible, marshalling is faster. @SathishKumar, using SharedPreferences for passing data between activities is a weird idea ...

Comment: @manish: If you need to reuse the user credentials in other activities means i prefer SharedPreferences is the best way, why because you can get it from any activity and you can able to clear it when you don't want further.

Comment: @Kuffs sorry, i thought that he need like session,  thank you, e

Comment: shared preference I don't see it as solution, maintaining as static is better option.Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can have one Application class in your project like:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private User user;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public void setUser(User user){
        this.user=user;
    }

    public User getUser(){
        return user;
    }
}
```

Or you can have some static class or some interface to hold application state (I.E. your user object)

In app manifest

```
<application android:name="<-pkgname->.MyApplication" ......>
```

and at any activity in your application you can get it as

```
MyApplication myApp=(MyApplication)getApplicationContext();
User user=myApp.getUser();
```

Comment: No need for that just set name to your application in AppManiFest

<application
        android:name="<Your application class name>" >

Comment: I think here's actually nothing preventing you from creating another instance once you subclass Application. An even better way is to implement you own singleton class. See https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AnderWebbs/posts/DsfpW51Vvow

Comment: You can make this class singleton as well, but i think the real benefit of MyApplication class is that it can be accessed via context.

Comment: My point was that you SHOULD implement it as a singleton, as having 2 instances of your application class is an extremely bad idea...

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data as a static variable. So the data will be maintain throughout the application scope.

The best practice is to store data in the Shared Preference.